# iPhoto album transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iphoto

I am trying to implement the same scrolling effect in the apple iphoto album. Hope you have seen in apple iphoto that when we move the mouse over the album, the images inside it will be shown one by one. Anyone knows how this is implemented.? i am trying to implement the same in my HTML page.

Please Help

Thanks,

Shibin

Answer (score 4):

try the [iskip](http://www.iantearle.com/projects/iskip) jquery plugin

Comment: This looks to be exactly what Shibin was looking for. Should be accepted as the answer, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any JavaScript experience? I'm sure you can create that effect using JS, however I'm not super familiar with JS (yet). For a very simple version of the effect though, you can manipulate the DOM to change the image upon mouseover like so:

```
<a href="#" onMouseOver="document.my_image.src=new_image.gif;">
<img src="http://example.com/image.gif" name="my_image"/></a>
```

Try adding a javascript tag to your question, maybe then a more experienced JS ninja will be able to help you out.